# How to get filepath in class Library

Tags: asp.net-core

I am creating a class library and I want to get path of a file in the library package. I tried to use `IApplicationEnvironment` but it gives me the error

> NULL Reference exception

Comment: where are you trying to use `IApplicationEnvironment`? please post some code

Comment: Inside a class.

namspace TestLibrary{
public class TestClass{
private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _appEnvironment;
protected void Style()
        {
File.OpenRead(_appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath + "filename")
}
}